# Keep DataGridView BindingSource From Updating a Particular Column's Cell Values

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatable, bindingsource

I have a `DataGridView` that is bound to a `DataTable` using a `BindingSource` and not all of the columns in the `DataGridView` are bound to that `DataSource`'s properties. To be more specific I have a custom `DataGridViewColumn` for multi selection that is derived from the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` class and has a master checkbox that controls the others that is located in the column header. My issue is that whenever `DataTable.AcceptChanges` is called the `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` reverts back to its default value (False) and I lose my previous selection. Does anyone know of a nice way to prevent or side step this behavior?

Essentially, I would like to retain the cell values that are in that column even after `DataTable.AcceptChanges` is called because they do not pertain to the underlying data source.

Here is some sample code that reproduces what I'm experiencing. Check some of the check boxes in the selection column and press `Ctrl+S` and notice that you will lose those checks every time even though they are not bound to a specific `DataGridViewColumn`. I realize that this is probably the nature of the `BindingSource` but I'm wondering if there is a way around this behavior. Also, I would like to avoid writing logic that saves what rows are selected before `AcceptChanges` is called and then resets them after `AcceptChanges` returns. To me this seems too cumbersome if we have a ton of rows selected in the `DataGridView` at one time. Anyone got a more hackish idea?

```
Public Class Form1
  Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim dgv As New DataGridView
    dgv.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn With {.HeaderText = "Selection"})
    dgv.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.HeaderText = "ChangeMe", .DataPropertyName = "ChangeMe"})
    Controls.Add(dgv) : dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Dim dt = New DataTable : dt.Columns.Add("ChangeMe", GetType(String))
    For Each thing In {"Shoe", "Boat", "Rat"} : dt.Rows.Add(thing) : Next
    dgv.DataSource = New BindingSource(dt, Nothing)
    Me.KeyPreview = True
    AddHandler Me.KeyDown, Sub(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
                               If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then dt.AcceptChanges()
                           End Sub
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the `BindingSource` raising a [BindingSource.ListChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.listchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) of type `ListChangedType.Reset` in response to the `DataTable.AcceptChanges` method.  When the `DataGridView` receives this event, it reloads from the `BindingSource.`  This occurs in the [ProcessListChanged Method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewDataConnection.cs,2cc4e2a42be6fd3c) (scroll down to line 658).

A possible work-around is to prevent the `BindingSource` from raising events during the execution of `DataTable.AcceptChanges` by modifying the key handler method to be like the following.

```
    AddHandler Me.KeyDown, Sub(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
                                            If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
                                                Dim bs As BindingSource = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, BindingSource)
                                                bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = False
                                                dt.AcceptChanges()
                                                bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
                                            End If
                                        End Sub
```

Comment: I quite like this, but my dilemma is that in my current project `AcceptChanges` is called within another class. I suppose I could have that class raise an event before and after `AcceptChanges` is called to prompt the UI layer to listen for those events and enable/disable the `RaiseListChangedEvents` on the `BindingSource`, seems clunky though. I would have bumped this if my reputation was higher, thanks.

Comment: @lizaardman04, that information should be included in your question.  Specifically, that the repo code does not reflect your actual situation.  If the call to `AcceptChanges` is in another class, what action in your UI causes it to execute?  Can you not wrap that action with with a similar logic as shown above?  If not, show how the `BindingSource.DataSource` property refers to the underlying `DataTable`. Does the `DataTable` originate in this other class?  In short, if you expect to get a specific solution, you need to provide all the information that could influence the proposed solution.